# Graph SDK O365 - MIME Type always returning as empty JSON

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am following the [O365 Graph SDK Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) for obtaining the MIME content of a message.

After receiving a message from a mailbox scrape, I attempt to then grab the MIME content so I can also save it as an EML in blob storage:

```
return $graphSdk->createRequest('GET', sprintf('/users/%s/messages/%s/$value', $this->config['from_email'], $message->id))
    ->setReturnType(MimeContent::class)
    ->execute();
```

However, this always returns an empty JSON response, even when attempting to do it inside of the Graph Explorer.

Weirdly, if I change the ID to anything else, it throws a 400 (bad request) with an invalid ID so I know the ID is correct... I just cannot seem to obtain the MIME type from the endpoint.

This is a shared mailbox and I have all permissions to it (hence why I can read the folders). Any ideas to why its runing an empty JSON? This is returning empty in every message ID I try and I've also tried to point it at the correct mailbox URL with no luck:

```
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/messages/{id}/$value
```

Which gives me for a GET request:

> The OData request is not supported

Again, if I remove `/$value` from the URI, it works fine and I get the message content... It seems I just cannot get the MIME content...

I have also decided to track this on the Github repo under [Issue #1210](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/issues/1210) as I'm unsure if this is SDK related.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response) says:

> Specifying the $value parameter returns the message content in MIME format, and not a message resource.

In other words, it doesn't return a JSON content but directly the message as `text/plain`, as shown in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-get-mime-content).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! It works as expected in delegate flow, but doesn't work in application flow - I am aware of the return types and have tested it substantially in Graph Explorer. Is there any way to get it to work in application flow? The docs do not say it isn't supported, there is only a hint: "The fourth example gets the MIME content of a message in the signed-in user's mailbox." which is the only example which makes me think only delegate flow is supported for MIME content requests?

Comment: @Jaquarh I have no idea what "delegate flow" and "application flow" mean.

Comment: Delegate flow is when the user signs in and grants permission to the requested scopes, application flow is pre-shared secret and permissions. I am not using oAuth 2.0, I am using the application flow on a pre-shared key which means I am not acting on behalf of a "signed in user". When I switch to oAuth 2.0 (delegated access) then it works fine, if I do the same on the pre-shared key's access token (not as a signed in user) the above doesn't work - but this is not suggested in the docs, anywhere - I am asking if its still possible and if so how?